# AD7147-1 CDC Conversion Complete Interrupt

Tags: adc

I have three stages connected, Stage0, Stage1, and Stage2. So I want to enable the interrupt after Stage2.

So I write,

STAGE_LOW_INT_ENABLE  (Address 0x005) = 0b0000000000000000

STAGE_HIGH_INT_ENABLE  (Address 0x006) = 0b0000000000000000

STAGE_COMPLETE_INT_ENABLE (Address 0x007) = 0b0000000000000100

Then I read the STAGE_COMPLETE_INT_STATUS Register (Address 0x00A) by my read function.

When I read the STAGE_COMPLETE_INT_STATUS Register (Address 0x00A), it doesn;t print 0b0000000000000100.

Instead sometimes it prints 0b0000000000000111, sometimes 0b0000000000000101, sometimes 0b0000000000000110. But never prints 0b0000000000000100.

So I want to know how can I read the STAGE_COMPLETE_INT_STATUS Register (Address 0x00A) and asserts interrupt when all three conversion stages are complete and my microcontroller will read data from the ADC through I2C.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing anything that looks wrong in your question; are you having any problem with the ADC readback, or just asking why bits 0 and 1 might also be set when bit 2 is set in STAGE_COMPLETE_INT_STATUS?

I'm not familiar with this part, but it looks like bit 2 of STAGE_COMPLETE_INT_STATUS tells you that stage 2 of the conversion is completed. If you set SEQUENCE_STAGE_NUM to 2, that should mean the entire conversion is completed. Bits 0 and 1 are sometimes set if the *next* conversion is starting to be processed; it shouldn't strictly be a problem, though you probably need to handle the interrupt within a certain time limit to avoid losing the sample if that's important to you.

Are you setting the SEQUENCE_STAGE_NUM register to 2 to tell the part you only have 3 inputs connected? (At least I think that might be how it works...)